# Update event calendar android

Tags: android, события, google-calendar

Здравствуйте, после создания мною ивента (в моём апп). Пытаюсь его изменить (тоже из апп):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, from.getTime());
values.put(Events.DTEND, to.getTime());
values.put(Events.TITLE, titleSpot.getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location.getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 0);
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION,
dis.getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
values.put(Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1);
values.put(Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, 1);
values.put(Events.GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY, 1);
values.put(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI,spot.eventId);
cr.update(uri,values, null, null);
```

Но он, по какой-то причине, после выполнения этого кода удаляется из календаря.

Comment: А пермишены применили?

`android.permission.READ_CALENDAR`
`android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR`

Comment: Была какая-то гнусная история с этими ивентами в календаре. Ее отменяли и говорили, что-то типа того, что приложение календарь нестандарто и каждый вендор будет сам ее поставлять. Потом по-моему с API 16 вроде как вернули обратно сказав, что стандартным календарем будет Calendar Google. Так что поиграйте с API левелом.

Comment: target 17  у меня,с 8 по последнюю.Менять нельзя , что же блин делать=\

Comment: Кстати, я и дальше могу пытаться апдейтить ивент , то есть ошибки когда я пытаюсь изменить ивент с айдишником нету , операция так же возвращает количество измененных строк , но в календаре ивента нету(

Comment: Собери под API-17, с minSDK=8 и еще привлеки android support library - может поможет.

Comment: Я и так это с самого начала делаю...Все ивенты которые я создал и изменял продолжают существовать и изменятся , я это проверил получив все ивенты из календаря.Следовательно кого-то *** они просто не показываются в календаре после апдейта=///
Тааак,я заметил  что у меня трабл со временем, почему то когда получаю бегин энд время ивента после создания , оно вообще 2018 года,хотя в календаре всё нормально до апдейта

Comment: Меня смущает: `Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE` - может дело в этом?

Comment: Да я тут всё не нужное убрал.Со времени после создания всё более менее норм.число то же,правда часы не такие , всегда 07:00...
Вроде всё работать стало...хз что сделал...Со временем немного помучился...